# Account vs Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, account, account-management

My Client is mainly into Service oriented and wants to store Vendor Companies under Custom Object and Partner Companies under Account object.We could use record types and store both Vendors and Partners under Account.What are the advantages of using Account Object vs Custom Object?

Answer (score 1):

Account object ideally be used for defining companies, institutions etc. and here Vendor Companies can be defined as a separate record type and can be stored as Account record itself.

If you store the Vendor companies as Accounts there could have following advantages that I can think of:

1. Leveraging Salesforce Standard objects instead of defining a new one.
2. Grant Access using Hierarchy by default always applicable for Account and all standard objects, where for Custom objects you can un-check it. So role based record visibility can be streamlined.
3. You can leverage Account Team for sharing of Account records
4. Think about that if Opportunities needs to be defined under Account that could be M-D relationship, you can define rollups. But for defining Custom object, that relationship cannot be achieved.
5. Maintenance of extra object, tab, fields are not needed and most of the Account fields can be reused.

Comment: My client mainly deals with  force.com apps.So can you tell me how advantages are related to force.com?

Comment: same advantages, ultimately you will be leveraging CRM data model for force.com

Comment: @sfdc The company I work for writes force.com apps and we assume that customers are using Account objects for companies: following defacto conventions improves the chances that your org will work more easily with apps (so requiring less integration work).